# 'Why were you late?'

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

'Why were you late?'
'Because my car_______on the way here.'
a) was breaking down
b) had broken down
c) broke down

Could you please answer to this questioin and explain why?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please improve your question by describing how you have already tried to research an answer (for example, by adding a link to grammar book) and what still confuses you.

Comment: https://g.co/kgs/xpWCCS, unit 9

Comment: It is a good idea when you are copying a question from a text book to include "I think the answer is ....  Because .... But I am not sure because ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think is the break down, an event, a progressive or repeated process, or a state resulting from a prior event.

For example an event might be "running out of petrol". For a past event you would use past tense

> ... because I ran out of petrol.

A process might be being repeatedly distracted by your children.

> ... because my kids were fighting in the back.

A state resulting from a past action might be "not having petrol due to not refuelling earlier that day.

> ... because I hadn't put any petrol in the tank.

So you need to decide if "break down" is a repetitive process, a state resulting from a prior action or an event.

Comment: But OP had asked to choose from one of the three options. a) was breaking down b) had broken down c) broke down. Which one is right in your opinion and why?

Comment: Yes,  That was the question that was given to the OP  But I'm not doing their homework for them. I hope I've given enough guidance for them now to answer the question themself.  Just telling them "The answer is x" isn't much use.  But you are free to write your own answer (and downvote) if you think this one is no good